# Found error with my Batch file while trying to download a file from a website

Tags: powershell, batch-file

I was trying to create a batch file that downloads a file from website, after executing the batch file I found this error.

```
"Downloading CCleaner..."
Invoke-WebRequest : A positional parameter cannot be found that accepts argument '-'.
At line:1 char:1
+ Invoke-WebRequest https://download.ccleaner.com/ccsetup578.exe - Outf ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [Invoke-WebRequest], ParameterBindingException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : PositionalParameterNotFound,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.InvokeWebRequestCommand

"Done!"
Press any key to continue . . .
```

Here is the actual code below.

```
@echo off
echo "Downloading CCleaner..."
powershell -Command "Invoke-WebRequest https://download.ccleaner.com/ccsetup578.exe - Outfile setup.exe"
echo "Done!"
pause
```

[Error Screenshot.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/V3lv2.png)

Answer (score 0):

Remove the space between "-" and "OutFile"

```
@echo off
echo "Downloading CCleaner..."
powershell -Command "Invoke-WebRequest https://download.ccleaner.com/ccsetup578.exe -Outfile setup.exe"
echo "Done!"
pause
```

Comment: Hi, it works on my Windows 10 but does not works on Windows Server 2016. What could be the problem?

Comment: The first time you open a web browser as a user, you have to accept the Internet Explorer prompt, and this applies to running `Invoke-WebRequest` as well.  The prompt you should get should read 'The response content cannot be parsed because the Internet Explorer engine is not available, or Internet Explorer's first-launch configuration is not complete. Specify the UseBasicParsing parameter and try again.`  You can get around this by adding `-UseBasicParsing` to your `Invoke-WebRequest` line.

Comment: I tried replacing and adding next to it. Didn't work.

Comment: Can you give us your current code and error message please?